# mod_jk conflicts with mod_rewrite

Tags: apache, tomcat, mod-rewrite, mod-jk

I've got an Apache and Tomcat running and I use `mod_jk` to bind them. I have a Tomcat worker called "tc1" and the following setup on my `VirtualHost`:

```
JkMount   /* tc1
JkUnMount /*.png tc1
JkUnMount /*.gif tc1
JkUnMount /*.css tc1
JkUnMount /*.js tc1
```

That way Tomcat serves all requests apart the ones for static files.

Now I want to use `mod_rewrite` and do something very simple such as:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/foo$ /bar [L]
```

to rewrite the dynamic pageview at "/foo" to "/bar", but it doesn't work because all urls processed by `mod_rewrite` do not end up into `mod_jk`.

I've read the [Apache Tomcat Connector documentation](http://tomcat.apache.org/connectors-doc/webserver_howto/apache.html) and tried all of the `JkOptions` but nothing changed.

Does anyone know how to solve this?

Does the `mod_jk` and `mod_rewrite` load order and declarations ordering play any role in URL processing?

thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

That's odd, because by default a `RewriteRule` sends a client-side redirect, so the client should make a second request to /bar which should be caught by your `JkMount`. Does your access log show show the request for `/foo` and the the request for `/bar` also?

Try this rule instead:

```
RewriteRule ^/foo$ /bar [PT,L]
```

The "PT" means "pass-through", and is a rewrite bodge which allows you to mutate the URL in situ and lets other modules get a look in, without sending a redirect.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'll try that and post results. Note that I don't want a client side redirect, but a url rewrite.

Comment: Thanks a lot! PT (passthrough) is what I wanted!